# Fantasy book, main character called Spyder, a tattooist, meets a girl, ends up in a fantasy place

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find a book I read a few years ago. The main character was a guy called Spyder who I think was a tattoo artist, meets a girl at a bar, gets into a fight and I think he sees some weird stuff. Anyway somehow ends up in some fantasy place. All a bit weird.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specific things like when you read it. Can you provide any more details, any little thing you might think of?
Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 6):

[Butcher Bird](https://smile.amazon.com/Butcher-Bird-Dominion-Richard-Kadrey-ebook/dp/B006OOIA30/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1496172872&sr=8-2&keywords=butcher%20bird) by Richard Kadrey, 2007

Amazon synopsis:

> Spyder Lee is a happy man who lives in San Francisco and owns a tattoo shop. One night an angry demon tries to bite his head off before he's saved by a stranger. The demon infected Spyder with something awful - the truth. He can suddenly see the world as it really is: full of angels and demons and monsters and monster-hunters. A world full of black magic and mysteries. These are the Dominions, parallel worlds full of wonder, beauty and horror. The Black Clerks, infinitely old and infinitely powerful beings whose job it is to keep the Dominions in balance, seem to have new interests and a whole new agenda. Dropped into the middle of a conflict between the Black Clerks and other forces he doesn't fully understand, Spyder finds himself looking for a magic book with the blind swordswoman who saved him. Their journey will take them from deserts to lush palaces, to underground caverns, to the heart of Hell itself.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xy6pBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=fantasy%20spyder%20tattoo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT5p6MrpjUAhVK2oMKHQfMBSsQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) has at least some of it for reading to make sure it's the one.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks!

Comment: @Walker22 Glad to help.  If you think of it, hit the checkmark next to my answer so it gets marked as accepted.